# How to use css files in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new in Reactjs and working in Nextjs, I have some css files but i am confuse that where should use these css files,either in "index.js" or "app.js", i will create another pages also so where should i use following files ? Thanks in advance.
Here is my code in "index.js" file

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
export default function Home() {
  return (
<>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/font-awesome.css" />
```

Comment: Please always check the docs first: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support

Comment: in your project, there should be _document.js file if not you can create. and import there these styles. doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Comment: @AtulKumar Okay sir, but why we use _document.js ? why not in app.js ? Please explain

Comment: You don't need that, just import the stylesheets in pages/_app.js, like it says in the docs I linked you to.

Comment: @ChrisG i did but not worked means after click "ctrl+u",style.css not loaded

Comment: Please post the code you used and your project structure, it's most likely a path issue.

Comment: @ChrisG updated my question,Please check

Comment: But why not do this: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet

Comment: Just FYI, I installed the bootstrap module and added `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` in _app.js and it worked on the spot.